# Tell compiler to not generate debug info for standard libraries.

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-construction, include, g++

I have a project where I am analyzing DWARF information from C++ files. My system works well for simple C++ files, but gets messed up when I start adding #includes because the #includes dump in tons of extra (and generally unnecessary) code. Is there a way I can tell the compiler (g++) to not generate debug info for standard libraries? I would think so since when you debug code there are chunks where the IDE will says "source code not available."

Comment: as long as u compile w/ optimizations, i think no debug info is the default

Comment: @Kal - the OP wants debug info, but only for the 'user' code, not  the libraries.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Correct.

Comment: Maybe http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html is some help

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can tell the compiler (g++) to not generate debug info for standard libraries?

When you say "standard libraries", what you likely mean is STL, which has most of its code in the header files, and *because of that* STL code gets included into your program.

No, there is no way to tell GCC to generate debug info for some, but not all of the source code it compiles in a given translation unit.

> how then is the debug info only partially available in IDEs sometimes?

Unlike STL, *most* other libraries' code is *not* in the header files that you `#include`, but is in actual linkable library instead (i.e. in a set of different translation units, archived together into `libfoo.a`, or linked together into `libfoo.so`). These linkable libraries may be compiled with different flags, and often are compiled with optimization on and without debugging.

Comment: Since STL stands for *standard* template *libraries*, that was a safe assumption... yes. And are you sure about your answer? For example, how then is the debug info only partially available in IDEs sometimes? From my understanding its because the libraries are compiled as release version where as your code is compiled as debug version.